# Какое максимальное плавающее число можно записать в переменную?

Tags: javascript

Какое максимальное плавающее число можно записать в переменную? И какие хитрости есть при работе с подобными числами?

что делать, если надо получить высокую точность и очень большое значение?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#Properties ?

Comment: высокая точность = реализация длинной арифметики (на массивах) возни много ну или либу найти.

Comment: @D-side там почти ничего нет по плавающим числам. я вот это нашел https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Float64Array получается что в JS есть 64 разрядный FLOAT тип. Только вот как его использовать ..

Comment: @perfect спросили б лучше как его **не** использовать. В JS других чисел **просто нет**. Даже для побитовых операций происходит каст в целые, выполняется операция, а после каст обратно.

Comment: @D-side а почему тогда в вывод попадают только 17 знаков не считая точку? где остальное?

Comment: @perfect потому что [Числа двойной точности с плавающей запятой обеспечивают точность в 15—17 десятичных цифр](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8). Нет остального. Это максимальная точность. Дальше только мусор погрешности.

Comment: @D-side все ясно биты с байтами попутал. спасибо. А с большим количеством разрядов возможна работа в js?

Comment: @perfect ну, не стандартной библиотекой. А сторонних довольно много, смотря что вас интересует.

Comment: @D-side интересуют типовые математические операции + - * / и корень

Comment: Если интересует именно JavaScript, то https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/816-6408-10/number.htm#1193249 `The MAX_VALUE property has a value of approximately 1.79E+308. Values larger than MAX_VALUE are represented as "Infinity".`

Comment: Вы уверены, что ваш вопрос и правда часто задаваемый?

Answer (score -1):

Не знаю надо ли давать ответ, но может кому то поможет. Выход был найден с помощью библиотеки big.js Она поддерживает все базовые операции с большими числами. Все хорошо задокументировано.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[ссылка на этот проект](https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js/)

Comment: Это теперь так принято себя рекламировать, что ли?

Comment: @Akina не пойму о чем вы? этот проект не мой

Comment: Ну Вы задаёте основной вопрос, и вдогонку дополнительный. И публикуете собственный ответ на дополнительный вопрос, причём так, как будто ответ на основной вопрос Вас в общем-то и не интересует. Во всяком случае со стороны-то смотрится именно так... Может, есть смысл поправить или дополнить основной постинг (и м.б. сабж), чтобы ответ как-то соответствовал вопросу?

Comment: @Akina извините за прямоту. дополнительного вопроса не было а вот минус за свой вопрос мне поставили. и после 35 просмотров ответа не дали ... кто то должен был на него ответить им оказался я сам. и в итоге я звездун ... вместо упреков лучше давайте ответы если знаете ответ. вы взрослый человек.

Comment: *дополнительного вопроса не было* Основной вопрос (макс. значение) - сабж плюс первый абзац. Дополнительный (сверхдлинные) - второй абзац. И они практически не связаны между собой, чтобы можно было посчитать это уточнением. *ответа не дали* по основному вопросу я дал ссылку на документацию и цитату из неё. *минус за свой вопрос мне поставили* - увы, но огорчу - и минус, и голос за закрытие не от меня.

Comment: @Akina то есть вы считаете что размер переменной и точность вещественного числа никак с собой не связаны?

Comment: В строковую переменную можно закатать число из 4 гигабайтов девяток... устроит? и точность в триллионы значащих цифр, между прочим... У Вас потрясающая способность забывать свои собственные вопросы, даже если их можно перечитать.

Comment: @Akina ага а потом получить ее корень!? и за чем же числовой тип нужен тогда в JS? Его для смеха придумали, правда? И хватит меня упрекать, что я что то забываю, переписываю, звездю. Сами ересь несете а на меня пальцем тычете.