# Какое максимальное число разрядов в цифре Javascript

Tags: javascript, ieee-754, числа-с-плавающей-точкой, int

Я знаю, что максимальное целое число в js равняется 9 007 199 254 740 991. А если добавить после целого числа точку, получается с плавающей точкой. Я прочитал на сайте w3c, что максимальное количество цифр после точки может быть 17. Но если после точки уже есть 17 цифр, то сколько может быть перед точкой. Есть ли какая то зависимость (думаю что есть) и какая, и где об этом можно почитать.

Comment: [6.1.6 The Number Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-language-types-number-type)

Comment: Вот вы сами местку поставили ieee-754 - вот там все и описано, про точность и чосило значащих цифр. А дальше вопрос только в том, сколько-байтное число с точкой использует JS.

Comment: @Kromster _representing the double-precision 64-bit format IEEE 754-2008_

Comment: Вот подобный вопрос с полезными ссылками: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/662452

Comment: я почитал стандарт, статьи которые должны бы вроде обьяснять как работает, и теперь я знаю меньше чем до этого, как можно так непонятно обяснять? есть может где нормальное обьяснение стандарта, что к чему, как..